# How to deploy docker image from Github Package Registry to Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps, github-package-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have Github Package Registry about Docker Image. I want to deploy it to Azure Web Apps. I try the setup like this,

1. Server URL: https://docker.pkg.github.com
2. Full Image Name & Tag: berviantoleo/my-telegram-bot/my-telegram-bot:latest

I'm not fill the username & password, because it is public docker image. I also already try to bring username & password, but no luck, still failed to pull.

I see from the logs, it have logs like this:

```
2020-11-16T02:46:04.868Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: berviantoleo/my-telegram-bot/my-telegram-bot:latest
```

It's very weird because I already change the Server URL, is it the Server URL only support Docker Hub? I need help about this. I already try from Dockerhub, yeah, it can be deployed. But for now, I want to try from Github Packages Registry.

Update:

- I've made mistake, the fullname should be: `docker.pkg.github.com/berviantoleo/my-telegram-bot/my-telegram-bot:latest` need include the `docker.pkg.github.com`
- When change to private repository and provide username and password, it can pulled the image.
- When public repository, it still need username and password, maybe because I misunderstand about the package. I think `docker.pkg.github.com` still need to be authenticated. I get this log:

  ```
   2020-11-18T03:33:57.973Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://docker.pkg.github.com/v2/berviantoleo/tele-bot/tele-bot/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials"}
  ```
- I still need to find solution that no need username and password.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: For set it to private registry and provide username and password, it can be pulled correctly. I think I misunderstand about github package. The public repo still need username and password so web app can pull the image, I think `docker.pkg.github.com` need authenticated account to pull the image no matter public or private. Also I made mistake about the fullname. I've changed to correct fullname, in the azure webapp can pull the image.

I can say the problem not come from azure web app, it's my mistake. The log from azure web app confusing actually.

Comment: If the answer is helpful and solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: If you have any more questions on this issue, please let me know. If it works for you please accept it. It's not difficult to accept.

Comment: Sorry, I still need to pull from Github Package with public repository but without username and password. I know it will very specific by Github Package itself. But, that's what I want to find out. Sorry, your answer acceptable for the general question, but not for my current problem.

Comment: If you use the Azure Web App, what I said is the answer. There is no other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you pull the image from the public registry then you do not need to set the credential, and by default, the public registry is the docker hub. For other registries, private registry, you need to set the environment variable `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL` to tell the Web App to pull images from it. And set the `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME` and `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD` for the credential. For a quick test, the image you used should be in the private registry. So you need to set the credential for it.